# Symbolic matrix simplification and solving

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, symbolic, vector, vector-calculus

I am trying to expand or solve an equation that contains matrices for a certain matrix, but it is not working:

```
$Assumptions = 
  {Element[X, Vectors[n]], Element[Zu, Vectors[n]], 
   Element[Fu, DiagonalMatrix[n]], Element[Y, Matrices[{n, n}, Reals]]};

Solve[Y.Fu.(Zu + X.Y) + (Zu + X.Y).Fu.Y + 2 λ X == 0, X]

ExpandAll[Y.Fu.(Zu + X.Y) + (Zu + X.Y).Fu.Y + 2 λ X]

Simplify[Y.Fu.(Zu + X.Y) + (Zu + X.Y).Fu.Y + 2 λ X]
```

None of the above inputs works. Am I doing something wrong or is it that *Mathematica* cannot solve for matrix equation symbolically?

Comment: Anyway, Mathematica still lacks proper matrix symbolic manipulation, except for some basic stuff. You, me and many others are hoping it comes soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to proceed:

```
n = 3;
xvec = Array[x, n];
zvec = Array[z, n];
ymat = Array[y, {n, n}];
fumat = DiagonalMatrix[Array[fu, n]];

Solve[ymat.fumat.(zvec + xvec.ymat) + (zvec + xvec.ymat).fumat.ymat + 2 lam*xvec == 0, xvec]
```

The output is a fully symbolic answer for the terms of `xvec`, albeit not in as compact a form as one might wish.

The `Assumptions` command does not work as you wish. In particular, assumptions are not carried over from the first line to the later lines of your code. You can see this by looking at the `FullForm` of your variables.

Comment: Thank you very much I had already seen a similar answer, but I was looking if there is any way to gather them in matrices again?

Comment: I guess the only hope would be to try something in the `Tensor` commands:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html

Comment: Thanks but it uses assumptions I though the were the right case. Could you please give me an example of how this would work in my case or a similar one?

Comment: The difficulty is that there is no `TensorSolve` and regular commands (like `Solve`) don't honor the tensor assumptions. I have never used these commands. Maybe someone else has figured it out.